# Read byte array from HttpRequest body

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I am trying to retrieve byte array from HttpRequest post body. The post body contains object with two properties. 1. "Id" is of type `string` and 2. "Data" is of type `byte[]`.

The Data property contains file data converted into byte array using code :

```
Data = File.ReadAllBytes("fileName");

var responseObj = JObject.Parse(await new StreamReader(request.Body).ReadToEndAsync());

string id = responseObj["Id"].Value<string>();
var data= responseObj["Data"].Value<byte[]>();
```

The last line of code is giving me exception.  I am trying to store byte array into a file and then retrieve at later stage.

Comment: Those bytes are likely string encoded somehow. You need to figure out what that encoding is (base64 or hex or something else), then you can parse that into a byte array. If you want more help you will need to post sample json content that could actually be parsed (not just random data, that does not do anyone any good).

Comment: not sure what encoding readAllBytes uses. There is no enough documentation on microsoft page. "Opens a binary file, reads the contents of the file into a byte array, and then closes the file."

Comment: That first line of code has nothing to do with your problem right? `Data` is not referenced by the other lines of code in your example and the last line of code is throwing the exception. The issue as I understand it has to do with the last line of code and my first comment is about that line of code. The parsed json object has binary data but it is encoded, you need to figure out what that encoding is so you can convert it to a byte array.

Comment: Yes, first line of code is not used in my code. The other team is creating byte array using File.ReadAllBytes and posting the data. I am trying to read it.

Comment: Can you show an example of what the JSON data looks like?  Assuming the `JObject.Parse` line is working OK, dump out `responseObj.ToString()`.  I'm particularly interested in what the `Data` property looks like in the JSON-- i.e. is it an array of integers or is it a base64 string?

Comment: You should consume either binary data or string. not both. so use json and get encoded binary data and decode the response to byte array.

Answer (score 1):

**I guess you are using HttpClient class to make the request**

Simple as this:

var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()

Comment: Content contains Id and Data. I want only Data as byte array, not entire content.